# Wanted: encryption scheme for copy protection purposes

Tags: encryption, copy-protection

I am tasked with implementing a dongle-based copy protection scheme for an application. I  realize that no matter what I do, someone will crack it, but I want to at least make it a little more difficult than an if-statement checking whether a dongle is present.

My approach is to encrypt critical data that the application needs for proper execution. During runtime, the decryption key is retrieved from the dongle (our chosen model has some suitable API functions for that), the data is decrypted and the application is happy.

Of course, a determined attacker can intercept that decryption key and also get ahold of the decrypted data. That's ok. But what should be hard is to substitute their own data. So I'm looking for an encryption scheme where knowing the decryption key doesn't enable someone to encrypt their own data.

That's obviously asymmetric encryption. But for every such algorithm I found so far, the encryption (or public) key can be generated from the decryption (or private) key, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Note: simply signing the data won't help much, since (unless I'm totally misunderstanding such signatures) verifying the signature will just be another if-statement, which is easily circumvented.

So... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question (somewhat), it is possible to do this with RSA, but most APIs (including the one of OpenSSL's crypto library) need to be "tricked" into doing it. The reason you can generate the public key, given the private key, is that

1. It is common practive for implementations of RSA to save p and q (those big prime numbers) in the private key data structure.
2. Since the public key (which consists of the modulus N and some exponent e) is public anyway, there's (usually) no point in choosing an obscure e. Thus, there are a handful of standard values that are used commonly, like 3 or 65537. So even if p and q are unknown, you might be able to "guess" the public exponent.

However, RSA is symmetrical in the sense that anything you encrypt with the public key can be decrypted with the private key and vice versa. So what I've done (I'm a monster) is to let the crypto library generate an RSA key. You can choose your own public exponent there, which will later be used to *decrypt* (contrary to the normal way). Then, I switch around the public and private exponent in the key data structure.

Some tips for anyone trying to do something similar with the crypto library:

1. In the RSA data structure, clear out everything but n and e / d, depending on whether you want to encrypt or decrypt with that particular key.
2. Turn off blinding with RSA_blind_off. It requires the encryption exponent even when decrypting, which is not what we want. Note that this might open you up to some attacks.

If someone needs more help, leave a comment and I'll edit this post with more information.

Answer (score 3):

The moment the private key is known to the attacker you won't have any secret information to differentiate yourself from the others. 
To make it harder for the attacker: You might want to expire each pair (public key, private key) after an application specific time T and generate a new pair based on the previous pair both on the dongle and your own machine, independently. This way the attacker needs to have a constant access to the dongle to be able to encrypt his data with the new private key or to run his private_key_detection algorithm as often as T.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion with expiring keys. Wouldn't I have to constantly re-encrypt the data with the new keys? That's no problem when I'm building a new version, but once the software is installed on a client's machine, that could lead to problems (e.g. write permissions for the files).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to run the decrypt on the dongle.  There are a few pieces of hardware that help this ([I just googled this one, for example.](http://www.securemetric.com/securedongle.php)).  There are likely many others....Dallas Semiconductor used to have a Java button that would allow you to run code on a small dongle like device, but I don't think they have it anymore.

Some of these allow you to execute code in the dongle.  So maybe a critical function that is hard to recreate yet doesn't require high performance might work?  Perhaps a license key validation algorithm.

Maybe you could include code in the dongle that has to be put into memory in order for the program to run.  This would be a little harder to break, but might be hard to implement depending on what tools you are using to make your program.

You probably also want to study up on some anti-debugging subjects.  I remember seeing a few publications a while back, [but here is at least one](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3260).  This is another layer that will make it harder to crack.

Dependency on an Internet connection may also be an option.  You have to be careful here to not piss off your customers if they can't get your code to run without an Internet connection.

You can also check out FlexLM (or whatever it is called these days).  It works, but it is a beast.  They also try to negotiate a percentage of your company's gross profit for the license fee if I recall correctly (it's been years....I think we told them to stuff it when they asked for that.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link on anti-debugging! Unfortunately, my employer already decided on a particular dongle model without such capabilities and purchased some units, but I'm still hopeful I can convince them to switch to another, more intelligent one.

Comment: There are companies that exist to solve this very problem.  The entire company makes money on just this one issue.  It is a lot deeper than it seems on the surface.  Your employer would be better off buying a toolkit from one of these companies that provides you with the software and the dongles.  They'll probably spend (or lose) the same amount of money over time as your approach is proven or exploited in the field.  (I know most employers don't have enough vision to see past the up-front cost, but throw it out there just in case.)